# Pass request URL parameter into create view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am hoping this is a simple tweak. I've been reading through various threads here but I am missing a very basic step -- how do I grab the argument from the URL request?

For instance, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/student/item/create/8`

URL definition is `path('student/item/create/<int:pk>',views.CreateStudentBehaviorItem.as_view(),name='student_item_create'),`

My class view is as follows:

```
class CreateStudentBehaviorItem(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = StudentItem

    form_class = StudentItemForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('registration:student_item_list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateStudentBehaviorItem, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['pk'] = self.request.GET.get('pk')    
        return kwargs
```

The form is:

```
class StudentItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.course = kwargs.pop('pk', 'all')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Begin filtering by course ID 

        
    class Meta:
        model = StudentItem
        fields = ("item_student","behavior_category","behavior_item","response","internal_comments")
        widgets = {
        'item_student': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'behavior_category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'behavior_item': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'response': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'internal_comments': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows':5}),
        }
```

I haven't even gotten to the point to filter because I can't seem to get the PK from the request URL. My minimal Django experience is with get_context_data to grab request URL details. I hope this is a simple correction to grab the value.

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#path

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CreateStudentBehaviorItem, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return kwargs
```